# LRS plugin dropdown selections not working

Tags: linear-referencing

I have just loaded the LRS plugin but when I try to access the *layer with measures* drop down selections on the measure tab they are not working.  Calibration drop downs work and so to do the *layer* directly below *layer with measures*

[image]

I have reloaded the plug in, rebooted my computer, not sure what else to try.

calibration tab works fine but the locate, events and measures top option all have the same issue.

Comment: Did you actually have a layer with measure loaded ?

Comment: Hi, no I didn't. I had not created the LRS output file.  Now that I have it has worked perfectly.  Thank you for responding.